# Determine the height of paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have created table row headings as follows. I want to create a rectangle svg box across each of these 4 headings. I am unable to determine the paragraph height so unable to create boxes that exactly fit the paragraph. Here is my code

```
let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 1000).attr("height", 1000);

let text=[
"Who will win the election. Trump or Biden?",
"Data Analysis",
"Javascript",
"Compare Performance of S&P 500 Index against other Indices"  
]
svg.selectAll("boxestext")
    .data([0,100,200,300])
    .enter()
    .append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width", (d, i) => 100 )
    .attr("height", 200)
    .attr("x",(d, i) => d)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr("class", "boxes")
    .append("xhtml:body")
    .style("font", 50)
    .html((d,i)=>"<p>"+text[i]+"</p>")
```

https://codepen.io/zubair57/pen/MWeXPqX

Comment: Select the `p` (somehow, using d3). Then call `.getBoundingClientRect()` on it. The returned object will have a `height` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 1000).attr("height", 1000);

let text=[
"Who will win the election. Trump or Biden?",
"Data Analysis",
"Javascript",
"Compare Performance of S&P 500 Index against other Indices"  
]
let texty=svg.selectAll("boxestext")
    .data([0,100,200,300])
    .enter()
    .append("foreignObject")
  
    .attr("width", (d, i) => 100 )
    .attr("height", 200)
    .attr("x",(d, i) => d)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr("class", "boxes")
    .append("xhtml:body")
    .attr("class","mytext")
.attr("id",(d,i)=>"mytext"+i)
    .style("font", 50)
    .html((d,i)=>"<p>"+text[i]+"</p>") 

let rect = d3.selectAll("p").node().getBoundingClientRect()
console.log(rect.height)///
```

```css
p {text-align: left;}
.boxes p{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```